# Select specific columns from a record using only 'sed' without using 'awk'

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

Here are some sample input I obtain from doing `ls -l` :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1779 Jan 10  2014 zcmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    5766 Jan 10  2014 zdiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     142 Jan 10  2014 zegrep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     142 Jan 10  2014 zfgrep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2133 Jan 10  2014 zforce
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    5940 Jan 10  2014 zgrep
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Dec  5  2015 ypdomainname -> hostname
```

I would like to print out the last column and 5th column using ONLY `sed` like this:

```
zcmp 1779 
zdiff 5766
zegrep 142
zfgrep 142
zforce 2133 
zgrep 5940 
ypdomainname -> hostname 8
```

I'm trying to find a regex to match but have not succeeded. And I'm not allowed to use `awk` or `cut` either.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "not allowed" sounds a lot more like homework than a question about how to accomplish a practical task.

Comment: And we're not here to do it for you, we're here to help you fix your code. Update  your Q with your best attempt to solve the problem, your current output, any error messages, and a general description of why you think  you code should work (or why it isn't), and you'll probably get some help. Good luck.

Comment: Also think about how your answer using 'sed' will tackle the situation when there is space in the name of some of the files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this;

```
 ls -l | sed -r 's/^(\S+\s+){5}(\S+\s+){3}/\1/' | sed 's/^\(.*\) \(.*\)$/\2\ \1/g'
```